# python: how to split this string with a regex?

Tags: python, regex

Simple one here but I'm fairly new to Python.

I have a string like this:

```
this is page one of an article 
<!--pagebreak page two --> this is page two 
<!--pagebreak--> this is the third page 
<!--pagebreak page four --> last page
// newlines added for readability
```

I need to split the string using this regex: `<!--pagebreak(*.?)-->` - the idea is that sometimes the `<!--pagebreak-->` comments have a 'title' (which I use in my templates), other times they don't.

I tried this:

```
re.split("<!--pagebreak*.?-->", str)
```

which returned only the items with 'titles' in the pagebreak (and didn't split them correctly either). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `*.?` into `.*?`:

```
re.split("<!--pagebreak.*?-->", str)
```

Your current regex accepts any number of literal `k`'s, optionally followed by (any character).

Also, I would recommend using raw strings (`r"..."`) for your regular expressions. It's not necessary in this case, but it's an easy way to spare yourself a few headaches.

Comment: `.*?` doesn't make sense in regex.

Comment: @jpm Yes it does. It's a `.` with a lazy `*` quantifier.

Comment: How can you forget about laziness? It is the greatest of all programming virtues.

Comment: @MattAndrews Not at all. We all make typos from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

You swapped the `.` with the `*`. The correct regex is:

```
<!--pagebreak.*?-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely an issue of swapping the . and *. "." matches all and the asterisk indicates that you'll take as many characters as you can get (limited of course by the non-greedy qualifier "?")

```
import re

s = """this is page one of an article 
<!--pagebreak page two --> this is page two 
<!--pagebreak--> this is the third page 
<!--pagebreak page four --> last page"""

print re.split(r'<!--pagebreak.*?-->', s)
```

Outputs:

['this is page one of an article \n', ' this is page two \n', ' this is the third page \n', ' last page']